# Shell script that runs python script again when it's finished

Tags: command-line, python, sh

I want to create a `sh` script that runs python script `python core.py` and when the script is finished pause for some milliseconds and run it again. And so on and on. Not sure where to start - any help appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure Watch waits for the python script to complete, so maybe not

Comment: Note that although the minimum time unit in GNU `sleep` is the second, it does permit fractional values ex. `0.0xy` for xy milliseconds. So you can use a simple `while ... sleep` loop as in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1254081/178692)

Comment: Yes but it says nothing about the command being complete before running again. I can not guess the sleep time, it will vary much.

Comment: @JohnT As mentioned in the answers of [this U&L question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/403537/what-happens-in-watch-when-the-called-command-has-not-yet-finished), `wacth` waits until the command is finished before running it again after the specified time interval.

Comment: Great! I will test it ASAP and get back here.